# Wordpress authenticate filter doesn't fire

Tags: wordpress, authentication, filter

I'm trying to implement a custom login authentication and am using the authenticate filter.

However, my code doesn't seem to be firing and after many tests I still can't figure out why.

I've tried stripping my code down to the essentials, but it still doesn't fire and I'm logged in every time instead of being rufused.

This is my stripped down code and it is inside my own plugin that is definitely being activated OK, as shown by a display messages I've put elsewhere in the code and it's definitely in the wp_filters array.

Can anyone see why it isn't being fired?

```
<?php
/**
 * Login functions
 */

add_filter('authenticate', 'ii_login_test', 30, 3);


/*
 * Custom Login
*/
function ii_login_test($user, $username, $password) {
    //return get_userdata(username_exists($username));
    return new WP_Error( 'authentication_failed', __( 'ERROR: No user record found.' ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try assigning `$user` to `WP_error()` and then return the user.

try out this code :-

```
<?php
/**
 * Login functions
 */

add_filter('authenticate', 'ii_login_test', 30, 3);


/*
 * Custom Login
*/
function ii_login_test($user, $username, $password)
{
    //return get_userdata(username_exists($username));
    $user = new WP_Error('authentication_failed', __('ERROR: No user record found.'));
    return $user;
}
```

Comment: Just tried it, but it still logs me in, so I guess the filter still isn't firing.